# How to Implement Forward To in SendGrid

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

I have checked the documentation of `Send Grid` but can't see any feature like `Forward To` , Can anyone let me know if there is any way to implement this feature like  is already there. I need to know about Forward.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "forward to"? Forwarding an email is a client-side function, not part of SMTP. SendGrid doesn't provide POP/IMAP mailboxes so there's no way to automatically forward messages received if that's what you mean. You might be able to use the [Inbound Parse webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) but you would have to write some code.

Comment: I mean like at Client side he is having an option to reply ,forward,, i have implemented the reply as it is present in the features of Sendgrid,, in that sense i was asking for Forward :)